# Not able to Select in Select Box over Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, drop-down-menu

I am facing issue when selecting options on selectbox only when the select option over my menu . The menu which I am using is an Plugin Jquery.

[image]

When the select box is over the menu the options is going back. I tried giving z-index to my div but it didnt helped me. Can some one help me in solving this issue.. Its a new issue to me...

MY HTML:

```
<div id="top-search">
        <form nmae='name123' action="queryexecute.php" method="POST">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
        <select class="styledselect" name="field_2" style="width:100px;" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Show" required="">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="=">Equal</option>
            <option value="!=">Not equal</option> 
            <option value="LIKE">Like</option> 
            <option value="&gt;">Greater</option> 
            <option value="&lt;">Lesser</option>
            <option value="&gt;=">Greater than or equal to</option> 
            <option value="&lt;=">Lesser than or equal to</option>
            <option value="!==">Not identical</option></select>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <select class="styledselect" name="field_1" id="field_1" style="width:100px;" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Show" required="">
          <option value="">Select</option>
           <option value="`ShibAzmnNo`">no</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input name='' type="submit" src="images/shared/top_search_btn.gif"  />
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
#top-search {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: 46px -150px 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex

Comment: please share  your html or css which one you try this

Comment: Pro tip for future questions: Use jsfiddle.net to create a simplified version of your problem

Comment: this site you got your solution may i sure http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: @TomPHP Define #top-search{z-index:9999;}

Comment: sure @Litari will do it..

Comment: @RohitAzad can you pls post your solution as answer.. because your answer fixed my problem..

Comment: can some one tell me why it is downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its `z-index` issue you should increase the `z-index` of the parent element of select, to the parent element of menu

like

```
<div style="position:relative;z-index:9999">select item</div> 

<nav style="position:relative;z-index:99">menu items</nav>
```

OR

```
#top-search{z-index:9999;}
```

Comment: evn when i give my z-index to 20 the issue is still not getting resolved.. any idea?

Comment: please also give z-index to nav and it should be less than #top-search and also add position relative to the menu container

Comment: i did not do that if i down voted it why would i have answered it

Comment: i think people also want a fiddle link that y they down voted you

Comment: you are welcome because i have so much experience i can tell you with one sight that its a z-index issue but you should give a solid link to test your code that's the rule here